# how to load friends posts with firebase recycler adapter

Tags: android, firebase

I'm building a social app. I need to display friends posts in the main feed with firebase recycler adapter. I've tried many options but I'm not been able to do this, with the code below I'm only able to load posts of the current user. I'm pasting the code here please guide me in this regard.

I'm using 2 queries one for friends and other for posts

The  two database references are as follows

```
mUsersPostsDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts"); 

mFriendsDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(current_user_id);
```

The method is as follows

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

            Query posts = mUsersPostsDatabase
                    .orderByChild("user_id")
                    .equalTo(mFriendsDatabase.getKey());

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CurrentUserPosts, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CurrentUserPosts, UsersViewHolder>(
                        CurrentUserPosts.class,
                        R.layout.view_user_post_layout,
                        UsersViewHolder.class,
                        posts
                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(UsersViewHolder usersViewHolder, CurrentUserPosts model, int position) {
                                usersViewHolder.setImage_url(model.getImage_url(), getApplicationContext());
                                usersViewHolder.setUser_image(model.getUser_image(), getApplicationContext());
                                usersViewHolder.setUser_name(model.getUser_name());
                                usersViewHolder.setDate_time(model.getDate_time());
                                usersViewHolder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
                    }

                };
        mUsersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
```

The database node are like the following

Friends ---> current_user_id ----> friend_id

Posts ----> post_id ----> date, user_id, image_url, descp......

Comment: I have improved the spelling in your question a bit. I suggest you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49281772/edit) your question to fix the code part (remove extra enters and proper indentation) and fix any possible errors i made in the database structure.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. This is my first question so I didn't know how to edit it. Kindly guide me.

Comment: You can click on the link in my previous comment or use the edit button at the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Query friends = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

friends.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            String friendID = ds.getRef().getKey().toString();

            Query posts = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("posts").orderByChild("user_id").equalTo(friendID);

            posts.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        CurrentUserPosts newPost = new CurrentUserPosts();

                        newPost.setImage_url(singleSnapshot.child("image_url").getValue(String.class));

                        mPosts.add(newPost);
                    }
                    Collections.reverse(mPosts);
                    mUsersList.setAdapter(new UsersPostsThumbAdapter(mPosts));

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    String errormsg = databaseError.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errormsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```